# Add text above the comment button

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

I want to put some text above the comment button.

I use the following function :

```
function c_stackoverflow() {
    echo 'text';
} 
add_action( 'comment_form_after_fields', 'c_stackoverflow' );
```

It works properly, But when I move the comment textarea field to the end of the fields using the following code, The desired text is placed above the comment textarea field, How to put the desired text at the end of the comment textarea field above the send comment button?

```
function c_ccc( $fields ) {
    $comment_field = $fields['comment'];
    unset( $fields['comment'] );
    $fields['comment'] = $comment_field;
    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'comment_form_fields', 'c_ccc' );
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wis2Y.png)

Comment: If you check the place where this filter is actually executed, https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.2/src/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L2769, you find a comment above saying, `Fires after the comment fields in the comment form, excluding the textarea.`

Comment: The filters `comment_form_submit_button` and `comment_form_submit_field` are executed later, so you could try and insert your custom HTML there. But if you actually want to add an _input field_ to your form, then you should probably rather be using `comment_form_default_fields` to begin with.

Comment: Time is precious, CBroe Thank you for taking the time to answer my question, I found another solution which I am posting the answer to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little effort and thought, I found another solution :

```
function c_ccc( $fields ) {
    $comment_field = $fields['comment'];
    unset( $fields['comment'] );
    $fields['comment'] = $comment_field;
    $fields['comment'] .= 'text';
    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'comment_form_fields', 'c_ccc' );
```